# :set option to the output of expand()

Tags: vim

I'm adding a little logic to one of the options set in my `.vimrc`, something like this:

```
set backupdir=expand('<sfile>:p:h') . '/backup//'
```

The thing I can't figure out is how to do this expansion. It looks like `set=` just won't understand/execute a sub-function call like it would if I was doing a normal function call or using `let` for a local variable.

How do I pull off this expand + concatenation in a vim option?

Comment: Any attempts to solve this question by an inquiring Mr. Google have been quite obscured by `set` being an *extremely* common (and short) word. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:set` doesn't work with expressions, only with values. You have two solutions:

### Use `:execute`

```
execute "set backupdir=" . expand('<sfile>:p:h') . "/backup//"
```

See `:help :execute`.

### Use `:let`

```
let &backupdir = expand('<sfile>:p:h') . '/backup//'
```

See `:help :let` and `:help :let-&`.

Comment: Okay! So, is there any effective difference between `:set option=value` and `:let &option=value`? Glad `:execute`'s not my only option!

Comment: The fact that one accepts expressions ad the other doesn't is a pretty big difference, don't you think?

Comment: There a subtle diference also. `set+=` never adds the parameters twice. `let .=` will with several options